# How to include IE10 compatibie meta tag before primefaces default <script> inserts?

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf, primefaces, compatibility, meta-tags

I am trying to include the meta tag for IE compatibility as follows in my Primefaces JSF XHTML file.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"> 

<h:head>  
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE10" /> 
....
</h:head>
```

But the same is not taking effect in IE10 because before the meta tag, primefaces is including some script tags at the time of page render. 
Please check the following view source code from IE10.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/MyAppName/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces-aristo" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/MyAppName/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=4.0" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/MyAppName/javax.faces.resource/layout/layout.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=4.0" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/MyAppName/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=4.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/MyAppName/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery-plugins.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=4.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/MyAppName/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=4.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/MyAppName/javax.faces.resource/layout/layout.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=4.0"></script>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE10" />
```

If I remove these script tags (after saving the webpage) by editing, then the same is getting effected in IE10. Is there a way to include this meta tag before any primefaces default script tag inserts? I need this to make my application work fine IE10 without the user changing the compatibility setting by pressing F12.
JSF2.0
Primefaces4.0
IE10
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found this with some very simple googling...

Comment: Thanks a lot Kukeltje. I found the answer from that. I tried to google it but I couldnt find it. May be I need to improve my googling strategy. Can I please know what did you typed in google to find this answer? I thank you once again for helping me. I really appreciate it.